# Flutter want to pass context to Widget type

Tags: flutter

Widget cusSearchBar = Text("Supplier");

is there any way to pass the context to cusSearchBar. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I just want to point out that you're thinking in an imperative mindset instead of a declarative one.

Answer (score 3):

Extract as Widget

```
class CusSearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
      const CusSearchBar({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text('Supplier');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Widget cusSearchBar = _cusSearchBar(context, 'Supplier');

Widget _cusSearchBar(BuildContext context, String txt) {
  //use of context...

  return Text(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Widget cusSearchBar(BuildContext context){
return Text("Supplier");
}
```